# Asymptotic for the number of distinct prime factors of the non-zero values of non-constant polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, reference-request, prime-numbers, asymptotics

For $0\ne n \in \mathbb Z$ , let $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct positive prime factors of $n$ . If $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ is a non-constant polynomial then I can show that the set $\{\omega(f(n)) : n \in \mathbb Z , f(n)\ne 0 \}$ is infinite . So $\lim \sup_{|n| \to \infty , f(n)\ne 0} \omega(f(n))=\infty$ for any non-constant polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$   . My question is :  Given a non-constant polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$  , can we find an asymptotic formula or some order of magnitude for  $\lim \sup_{|n| \to \infty , f(n)\ne 0} \omega(f(n))$ or for $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty , f(n)\ne 0} \omega(f(n))$  (depending on $f(x)$ ) ?

Comment: Try with $f(x) = x^2-a^2$ (easy ?) and $x^2+b$ (harder)

Comment: @reuns : why are you talking about polynomials of specific form ?

Comment: It will show where are the difficulties