# On highly-composite values of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, divisor-counting-function

Can we characterize those non-constant polynomials $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ such that the set $\{|f(n)| : n \in \mathbb Z\}$ contains infinitely many "highly composite" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number)  numbers ?

Also see this related [Asymptotic for the number of distinct prime factors of the non-zero values of non-constant polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399930/asymptotic-for-the-number-of-distinct-prime-factors-of-the-non-zero-values-of-no)

Comment: well they can't be irreducible in theory, and might want to factor into the most irreducible polynomials possible. probably monic irreducibles are the main factors etc.

Comment: A comment exchange looked like it was spiralling downhill. Removed. Play chill.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was explaining things to the OP. In particular why at first he needs to restrict to the simplest polynomials..